# Sending wireless data over with xbee s1

Tags: xbee

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKVNmA8C6m8) to learn about Arduino wireless communication. I have 2 Arduino unos with Xbee S1s sitting on Xbee Pro shields.

I've programmed the Xbee S1s by screening into the /dev/tty/* and configuring them with: `+++, ATID1234, ATMY1000 (ATMY1001), ATDL1001 (ATDL1000)` and `ATWR`. I've double checked the values to ensure they are correct.

So i've created a super simple Sender and Receiver package:

Sender.ino

```
int counter = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(counter++);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Receiver.ino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Looping");
  while (Serial.available() == 0);    // wait
  int counter = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println(counter);
  Serial.flush();
  delay(500);
}
```

So first of all, when I upload my program to my arduino, I make sure that the S1s are not attached to the Pro shields which is attached to the unos.

When both of my unos are powered, I see a red light blinking but no indication of "busy blinking" which is supposed to happen when two XBee S1s are connected to the same channel. I am currently seeing a consistent blinking at about 1 second frequency.

Can someone tell me why I am only able to see "Looping" in my Serial monitor on my receiver?

Comment: So I was just hacking around and I finally figured out what went wrong! Apparently, there's a switch "XBEE/USB" that needs to be switched to XBEE for BOTH shields. After that, everything works as planned

Comment: Please add that as an answer, and accept your own question, if you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

**blah** reported:

> So I was just hacking around and I finally figured out what went wrong! Apparently, there's a switch "XBEE/USB" that needs to be switched to XBEE for BOTH shields. After that, everything works as planned.

Can someone vote this up please to remove it from the unanswered queue?